# Getting GRPC working when server is behind LB or Proxy

Tags: nginx, grpc

What are common solutions getting gRPC app running when there is a requirement to run through a some sort of proxy which does not support HTTP/2 toward origin, rather towards client side.

Were you people got this kind of setup done somehow?

The setup via proxy would create a flow similar to this:

```
Client <--- HTTP/2 ---> Proxy <--- HTTP/1.1 ---> gRPC Server.
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, it's not possible -- but stay tuned: [Piotr Sikora](https://github.com/PiotrSikora) from Google is trying to get HTTP2 upstreams supported on nginx, even though things are proceeding slower than one would expect:

- https://github.com/grpc/grpc.github.io/issues/230#issuecomment-306974585
- https://forum.nginx.org/list.php?29 (look for Piotr)